# Get data center information in Azure web role instance

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Folks,

Is there any way in a web role instance to get which Data Center (like North America) the instance in? I need this information to route my request to a proper subscription of table storage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will using Management API and making use of `<Location>` in *List Cloud Services* response do?

Comment: My understanding is that it can return a list location of a subscription, but probably not able to tell me in which data center my current web role in.

Comment: Well, what prevents you to iterate through each service, then through each deployment until you find your current deployment?